# Xperia J becomes little unresponsive after I make or receive a call

Tags: sony-xperia-j

My Xperia J becomes little unresponsive after I make or receive a call. I have to restart the phone afterwards. I did a factory reset and it worked for 3-4 days, but the problem comes again.

Answer (score -1):

Do a general reset all will be well. If you still have trouble, do a factory reset by holding the volume down and power buttons as you turn phone on.